# Need help understanding the scope of this javascript variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, scope

In javascript, within a VueJS SPA, I'm trying to create a method that will allow me to reduce redundant code by passing the Google Maps Places Service only a place_id and the fields I would like returned.

```
getPlaceDetails (place, fields) {
  this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
    var placesServices = new window.google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
    placesServices.getDetails({ placeId: String(place.place_id), fields: fields }, (result, status) => {
      if (status === window.google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result))
        return result
      }
    })
  })
}
```

I'm calling the above method from within another method:

```
var place = this.getPlaceDetails(place, ['name', 'geometry', 'place_id'])
```

It is invoked successfully... and the alert shows the desired JSON.. but place is null.  I've  tried using

```
var vm = this
```

above

```
var placesServices
```

and assigning the result to an app level variable... even inside of a .then after the first promise... like so:

```
getPlaceDetails (place, fields) {
  this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
    var vm = this
    var placesServices = new window.google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
    placesServices.getDetails({ placeId: String(place.place_id), fields: fields }, (result, status) => {
      if (status === window.google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result))
        vm.tempPlace = result
      }
    })
  }).then(function () {
    return this.tempPlace
  })
}
```

How can I get the method to return the result object??

Comment: promise.then is async, take a look at await https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: The return statement is part of the surrounding promise. You do not actually return anything in your method. Try to return the promise and react to it `this.getPlaceDetails(...).then((result) => {...}`

Comment: I guess that's what I was trying to explain that I was trying to do, @Scorpioo590.  I'm not clear on the appropriate syntax... or where the .then goes.

Comment: i've added my understanding of using .then in this case.... no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Promises

A [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is an object that will resolve (or reject) in some point in the future. This is necessary to execute asynchronous tasks (e.g. http-calls) that take an undefined amount of time to finish.

Promises can be *chained* i.e. get executed one after another. This is what the `.then` method does. With `.then` you pass a function that will be executed as soon as the promise is finished. This function will receive the object that was returned by the previous promise.

### Your method

```
getPlaceDetails (place, fields) {
    return this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
        var vm = this;
        var placesServices = new window.google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        placesServices.getDetails({ placeId: String(place.place_id), fields: fields }, (result, status) => {
            if (status === window.google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                return result;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This Method will return a promise that - at some point in the future - will yield the desired result.

When you want to call the method you get that promise and have to handle it, again by passing a function (using `.then`) that will be executed once the result is ready.

```
this.getPlaceDetails(...).then((result) => {
    // handle your result
}}
```

Alternatively you could use the [await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to wait until the promise is finished:
    var place = await this.getPlaceDetails(...);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return`ing the data, you may consider assigning the JSON to a Vue watched data variable, like so:

```
    var somePlace = new Vue({
      el: '#someEl',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello robwolf.io',
        tempPlace: {} // <- variable waiting for your asynchronous data if it comes thru
      },
      methods: {
      getPlaceDetails (place, fields) {
        // [...your promise code here...]
        }).then((result) => {
           this.tempPlace = JSON.stringify(result)
           // return this.tempPlace
        })
  // [...the .then function must also be an arrow function to have scope access to tempPlace...]
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me because getPlaceDetails is going inside of a forEach.  The data would be overwritten before I had a chance to do anything with it.  I'm trying to not build what I want to do with the data into the getPlaceDetails method... because I'm doing many different things with the data returned.

Comment: consider creating a new method which handles everything that needs to happen with each data being requested, and then calling that method with the data as the argument.

`}).then((result) => {
    let tempPlace = JSON.stringify(result);
    this.doSomethingWithTempPlaceMethod(tempPlace)
})`